# MySqlCommand.Parameters.Add adds slashes to commandtext in c#

Tags: c#, mysql

I'm trying to do a parametrized Insert query in C#, console application. DB = MYSQL 8.

```
StringBuilder commandString = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO testtable (testcol) VALUES ");
string testparam = "testvalue";
commandString.Append(string.Format("('{0}')", testparam));
commandString.Append(";");

string ConnString = "server = localhost; database = xxxxx; User = xxxxx; Password = xxxxx; port = 3306";

 MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection();
            conn.ConnectionString = ConnString;
            conn.Open();

            Console.WriteLine(commandString);  //if I copy the commandstring from the console and into Mysql workbench it works.

using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("@str", conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@str",MySqlDbType.Text).Value=commandString.ToString();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

Everything looks good, commandString is ok: INSERT INTO testtable (testcol) VALUES ('testvalue');

I get an exception stating the following:
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: 'You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''INSERT INTO testtable (testcol) VALUES (\'testvalue\');'' at line 1'

Please note the escape slashes in the message around 'testvalue'. I did not put them there and they do not show up in the commandstring prior to this line. Is this causing the error? And If so, why?

If I use cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue, I get the same working commandstring, but an error: System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' However if I copy paste the generated commandstring from the debugger to MySQL workbennch and execute it, it works.

Answer (score 3):

You aren't using parameterised queries correctly, you shouldn't covert the entire SQL string into a parameter as you do here:

```
using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("@str", conn))
{
     cmd.Parameters.Add("@str",MySqlDbType.Text).Value=commandString.ToString();
     cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

It doesn't do a straight text replacement, and you are in fact making things a bit more complicated than they need to be. An example might be:

```
string ConnString = "server = localhost; database = xxxxx; User = xxxxx; Password = xxxxx; port = 3306";
string testparam = "testvalue"; // realistically this might come from user input
string sql = "INSERT INTO testtable (testcol) VALUES (@testcol)";

using (var conn = new MySqlConnection(ConnString))
using (var cmd = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn))
{
    conn.Open();
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@testcol", MySqlDbType.Text).Value = testparam;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: Thanks GarethD for posting this example! For the future readers: I did add conn.Open() to the example make it work.

Comment: AddWithValue is safe to use with MySql, btw